# Update table column with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE micro_finance_loans AS 'ML' SET ML.Loan_status=11 
INNER JOIN micro_finance_customers AS 'MC' on MC.Customer_Id=ML.Customer_Id
WHERE ML.loan_status=10 AND MC.Number='4410188992243'
```

Can someone please tell me whats the error in this query, error as:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join microfinance_customers as mc on mc.CustomerId=ml.CustomerId
>       where ml' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE micro_finance_loans AS ML 
INNER JOIN micro_finance_customers AS MC on MC.Customer_Id=ML.Customer_Id
SET ML.Loan_status=11
WHERE ML.loan_status=10 AND MC.Number='4410188992243'
```

Comment: Hi, please remove invert comma from alias of table

Comment: error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
UPDATE micro_finance_loans AS 'ML' SET ML.Loan_status=11 from micro_finance_loans
    INNER JOIN micro_finance_customers AS 'MC' on MC.Customer_Id=ML.Customer_Id
    WHERE ML.loan_status=10 AND MC.Number='4410188992243'
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working ...
do you think, we use alias for second, 'from micro_finance_loans' ??